# as3 if statement not working (var loaded from php)

Tags: php, actionscript-3, if-statement

**UPDATE: Answered Below!**

I am calling a php script from a mobile device coded in as3 for Air. The php script works great and sends the right var back to as3.  I get the correct trace statement but the if statement is not working.

Here is the php line:

```
echo "done=success";
```

Here is the as3 code

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);
trace(variables.done); // WORKS echos out: success

// So I figured this line should work too, but it doesn't. Any ideas why?           

if(variables.done=="success")
{
// Does not work            
}
```

Comment: No idea, but could you try to store the value in a temporary variable? like `var done:String = variables.done` and see if that also traces out "success". If so, try to use it in your if statement and see if that works out.

Comment: I thought about trying that. I also thought about two other options that I will try as well. 1. Maybe "done" is a var in flash that is already used by the system and it does not like it or
2. Maybe I need spaces in the if statement. I am going to try all 3 options and I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks DidgerThud. I found out the issue was an extra white space at the end. I posed my answer with the code that worked below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHITE SPACE!

I found out the answer was an extra white space that php or as3 was adding in at the end. It could not be seen in the trace statement. I figured this out because I copied the trace statement and noticed there was an extra white space that I could highlight.

In short what looked like the word "success" (without the quotes) in a trace statement, was really the var "success " with an extra white space. Thus the if statement could not see it as "success" because it was really "success ".

To fix it I used this code:

```
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables(event.target.data);
trace(variables.done);

var itWorked:String = variables.done;
var rex:RegExp = /[\s\r\n]*/gim;
itWorked = itWorked.replace(rex,'');
if (itWorked == "success")
{
// Now it works. I hope this helps someone. 
}
```

Comment: you could also use `indexOf` if you don't want to do a `RegExp` - e.g. `if( itWorked.indexOf( "success ) != -1 )`